# Move sub directory to different directory using camel

Tags: apache-camel

How can I move sub directory containing files to different directory using `apache camel`.

for example
`/home/camel/inbox/tenant/aws/*.txt` to `/home/camel/processed/tenant/aws/*.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

UPDATED:

```
from("file:///home/camel/inbox/?recursive=true&delete=true&sortBy=file:name&include=(.*[.](txt|TXT)$)")
.to("file:///home/camel/processed/");
```

Comment: folder name `tenant` is dynamic :(